# Insert method Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, insert

I've been given an assignment to create a method that inserts a new element into the 4th index place of an array.

Here's my code:

```
def using_insert (array, new_element)  
  array.insert (4, new_element)
end
```

I don't understand why my code is giving this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' (SyntaxError)
array.insert (4, new)
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the spaces before the parenthesis.

So it should be:

```
def using_insert(array, new_element)
  array.insert(4, new_element)
end
```

Ruby allows to add a space before the opening `(` when you call a function with one argument, but when there are multiple arguments the space is not allowed.

Alternatively, you can just avoid the parenthesis altogether.